# Linux - Eclipse cpp 2019 06 - unhandled event loop exception when opening files

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt, gdk

When I install a fresh Eclipse, I can open the program, but when I attempt to create a new blank cpp file or open a file, the program stalls, I get a popup as seen below, and the terminal from which I launched the application looks like the 2nd attached pic. Can anyone help me with this? I'm not sure how to interpret these errors.

Popup:

[image]

Terminal:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this myself. In case this comes in useful to anyone else, the answer was found 
[here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=542675)

Essentially, before launching eclipse I type:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

The default value seems to be `xim`, and apparently is responsible for a number of issues. A small script could be made to automatically do this assignment, and then call eclipse.

This solved my issue.